# catching a 'PDOException' when database is down

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, exception

I am trying to catch an error if I cannot connect to database (eg xamp down or database connection down etc). I have tried to use `PDO::errorCode()` but yield no reuslts.

In my php I have a connection.php and a method ' to connect to the datatbase many times and return a new PDO instance to achieve various queries. The response displays the error message then all the php queries that call it, which also includes the name and password of the database in a non encrypted format.

- How can I catch this error and replace this error message with a human readable alternative (that doesnt display the name and password)?

CONNECTION.PHP

```
function connect()
{
    // set database server access variables:
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "password";
    $dbase = "dbName";

    //Establish a connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host."; dbname=".$dbase."", $user, $pass); //line 16
    $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    return $db;
}
```

RESPONSE

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it. ' in
>   D:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Web\htdocs\sitename\php\data\connection.php:16
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Web\htdocs\sitename\php\data\connection.php(16):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'password') #1
>   D:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Web\htdocs\sitename\php\function\active-user.php(28):
>   connect() #2
>   D:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Web\htdocs\sitename\map-floorplan.php(10):
>   include('D:\Users\Username...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   D:\Users\Username\Dropbox\Web\htdocs\sitename\php\data\connection.php
>   on line 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a try/catch to catch exceptions

```
try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host."; dbname=".$dbase."", $user, $pass); //line 16
    $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    return $db;
} catch( PDOException $e){
    $originalError = $e->getMessage();
    echo 'something went wrong.. '.$originalError; 
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you... seems simple now, just didnt know how to use `PDOException`.

Comment: Classes that extend from Exception or the Exception class itself can be catched. For more details check the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php